# Access an object through its name as a string c#

Tags: c#, winforms

I try to find out, how it is possible to access an object through a string which has the same name as the object name.
for example, I want to change the property of n times of Buttons using for loop

```
    public static object GetObject(string ObjectName)
    {
        // this Method has to return an Object through his name     
    }
    for (int i = 1; i < 4; i++)
        {
            GetObject(Convert.ToString("Button" +i) ).Text = Convert.ToString(i);
        }

    }
  

}
```

this code has the same function of this code

```
Button1.Text = "1";
Button2.Text = "2";
Button3.Text = "3";
```

Comment: I would suggest putting your buttons in a `Dictionary<string,Button>`, then you can give your buttons unique names and access them by `ButtonDict[name].Text = "1"`

Comment: What is your use case for this? Please provide more context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can develop different types of applications using `C#`. i.e. `Web`, `WinForms`, `WPF`. They have different types of `Control` and `Type`. I'm assuming that you are developing a `WinForms` application. In that case, you can use the `Controls` property of a `WinForm` to access all the `Controls` of a `Form`.

Please check the below code block for the implementation:

```
    public object GetObject(string ObjectName)
    {
        // this Method has to return an Object through his name     
        Control myControl = Controls.Find(ObjectName, true).FirstOrDefault();
        if (myControl != null)
        {
            // Do Stuff
            return myControl;
        }
        else return null;
    }

    private void RenameButtons()
    {
        for (int i = 1; i < 4; i++)
        {
            //GetObject(Convert.ToString("Button" + i)).Text = Convert.ToString(i);
            object btn = GetObject(Convert.ToString("Button" + i));
            if (btn != null) ((Button)btn).Text = Convert.ToString(i);
        }
    }
```

[image: Output]

You will find more details about the Controls property by following [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.controls?view=windowsdesktop-6.0#System_Windows_Forms_Control_Controls).

Answer (score 1):

you can try this

```
foreach (Control control in Controls)
{
   var btn = control as Button;

  if ( btn != null && btn.Name.StartsWith("Button") )
  {
      var i= btn.Name.Substring(6, 1)

       //if( i.Convert.ToInt32() <4 )  //optional
      btn.Text = i;
   }
}
```

Comment: `if (btn?.StartsWith("Button") ?? false) {...}`.